# dynamic binding of Button Content to an image button'sTextBlock?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a style for an image button as the following, how could I make the Text of the TextBlock, where equals "POSITION' below, the same as the Content of the button? Thanks.`

```
<Style x:Key="TopButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Button.BorderBrush" Value="SteelBlue" />
        <Setter Property="Button.BorderThickness" Value="0" />

        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="SteelBlue">
                        <Image Source="images/blue_button_up.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="POSITION" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Margin="5,5,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{Binding}` because the `DataContext` in the `ContentTemplate` is the `Content`.

Comment: you mean like <TextBlack Text="{Binding Content}....>"? Don't seem like to work that way.... I did work around it by creating a ControlTemplate of the image button though....

Comment: No, just `Text="{Binding}"`, that binds to the `DataContext` which is the content. In a `ControlTemplate` it's `Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"` (which is a bad idea, because `Content` is not restricted to text, one should use a `ContentPresenter`)